# To verify that element is displayed or not in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

```
public boolean addNewAlertIsDisplayed() {       
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='aside right am-slide-right']")).isDisplayed()) {
    return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am expecting false if it is not there..

But getting:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@class='aside right am-slide-right'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Why this exception is coming.. Is this needs to be handled in try/catch?

Comment: yes, if element is not availablein the DOM, then it will throw that exception. Need to be handled with try/catch block.

Comment: Seems you got an accepted answer but ideally you need to induce `try-catch{}`

Comment: @DebanjanB Best practice is to avoid throwing exceptions when unnecessary. This also follows the best practices outlined in the Selenium docs, `findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.` See [link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-).

Comment: @DebanjanB I don't understand your point. OP *is* using '.findElement` to validate whether the element is displayed. You are advising using `.findElement()` and a `try-catch()`... which is contrary to best practices and guidelines mentioned above.

Comment: @DebanjanB You understand that you are advocating an approach that goes against best practices and the Selenium documentation?

Comment: @DebanjanB That's a poor excuse for bad coding habits and promoting them to others. Lots of good devs "go by the books" AND "get the job done". This is a simple function. There's no reason to not follow best practices here, it works just fine, and it's cleaner/requires less code.

Comment: @JeffC Feel like to raise a question as per your requirement, stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public boolean addNewAlertIsDisplayed() {
  List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='aside right am-slide-right']"));
  return elements.size() > 0 && elements.get(0).isDisplayed();
}
```

If there are no elements it won't throw any exception. It will just be a list of size 0. Also as @Corey Goldberg mentioned, there should be checked if this element actually displayed. I forgot to add this to method.

Comment: just beware that this answer doesn't actually tell you if the element is displayed as the OP asked... it only checks if it exists in the DOM.    See the `isDislayedI()` method on `WebElement` to check if it's actually displayed.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg thank you for the feedback, nice catch! I have edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

Please check and use any one of the below two approaches.

**Approach 1:** 
you can find the Element using `findElements` method.If the element is found, then elementList size will be 1 or more than 1 and If the element is not found, then size will be 0. So, we can return the flag based on the condition,

```
    public boolean addNewAlertIsDisplayed(){
        List<WebElement> elementList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='aside right am-slide-right']"));

        //If the Element is not present , then the above list size will be 0, else it will have some value
        if(elementList.size()>0){
                return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Approach 2:** 
   You can check the element present using the try catch block as below

```
    public boolean addNewAlertIsDisplayed(){
        try{
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='aside right am-slide-right']"));
            return true;
        }catch(NoSuchElementException e ){
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you posting the same answers?

Comment: Best practice is to avoid throwing exceptions when unnecessary. This also follows the best practices outlined in the Selenium docs, `findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.` See [link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-).

Comment: neither of these solutions will tell you if an element is displayed... it only checks if they exist in the DOM.